# How to only remove single parenthesis and keep the paired ones

Tags: r, regex

Hello my dear teachers/ fellow R users,

I have recently started learning regex in earnest and recently I've come across a case where we only would like to keep paired parentheses `()` and omit the unpaired ones. Here is my **sample data**:

```
structure(list(t1 = c("Book (Pg 1)", "(Website) Online)", "Journal: 2018)", 
"Book1 (pg 2) book 3 (pg4)  something)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

And my **desired output** would be like:

```
structure(list(t1 = c("Book (Pg 1)", "(Website) Online", "Journal: 2018", 
"Book1 (pg 2) book 3 (pg4)  something")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I myself have managed to do it with the following code, but I thought there is surely a more efficient way of going about it. As a matter of fact I would like to learn other ways of doing getting the similar result:

```
test$t2 <- gsub("([(]?.*[)]?\\s+[^(]\\w+)[)]|([(].*[)])", "\\1\\2", test$t1)
test

                                     t1                                   t2
1                           Book (Pg 1)                          Book (Pg 1)
2                     (Website) Online)                     (Website) Online
3                        Journal: 2018)                        Journal: 2018
4 Book1 (pg 2) book 3 (pg4)  something) Book1 (pg 2) book 3 (pg4)  something
```

Another issue with my regex is when I swap the places of `RHS` and `LHS` of `|` it does not lead to the desired result which I'm curious why.
I would be grateful if you could give a little bit of explanation on solving these sorts of problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
> gsub("\\([^()]*\\)(*SKIP)(*F)|[()]", "", df$t1, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Book (Pg 1)"                          "(Website) Online"                    
[3] "Journal: 2018"                        "Book1 (pg 2) book 3 (pg4)  something"
```

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/qzPhPo) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Fzsfz/1).

*Details*

- `\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)` - `(`, zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char, and this matched text is discarded and the next match is searched for starting from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `[()]` - matches a `(` or `)` chars.

If you need to skip *balanced, nested* parentheses, you can use

```r
gsub("(\\((?:[^()]++|(?-1))*\\))(*SKIP)(*F)|[()]", "", df$t1, perl=TRUE)
```

Here, `(\((?:[^()]++|(?-1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)` matches and skips any substrings in between nested parentheses (like `(aa (bb(c)x)x)`) and `|[()]` matches any `(` and `)` in other contexts.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Fzsfz/2).

The `(*SKIP)` and `(*F)` (=`(*FAIL)`) PCRE verbs mean:

- [`(*SKIP)`](https://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#skip) - the engine advances to the string position corresponding to the place in the pattern where `(*SKIP)` was encountered, and starts a new match attempt at that position, or the engine skips to the string position corresponding to where `(*SKIP)` was matched—potentially saving a lot of fruitless match attempts
- [`(*F)`](https://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#fail) - signals failure to the regex engine triggering backtracking if applicable (here, it will because of the `|` alternation operator). Note that `(*F)` is the same as `(?!)`, i.e. fail if there is anything immediately on the right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm a bit struggling to understand this in particular what `(*SKIP)` and `(*F)` do here. I would be grateful if you could explain them a little bit to me.

Comment: @Jan Thank you very much for your response and also answer. Yes you are right, I will check them now.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I added brief explanation. I actually rarely explain in detail the PCRE verbs in the answers, I always think the short pattern explanation is enough. If the brief information is not clear please let know.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Mr. @WiktorStribiżew , you are right, I just need to take my time and study them since these concepts are new for me, but it's a great opportunity for me to learn more advanced stuff thanks to you. I will let you know if I have question and I truly appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Hi, I have started uploading some [regex videos on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFeq5T-LNtqpVrn_rcJ9hFw), feel free to check them out if you want to learn more about regex. As I am a novice in Youtubing, I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Hello, dear Wiktor. Thank you very much for informing me of your regex tutorials. I will certainly check them with great interest and thank you in advance for sharing your knowledge with others.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty straight-forward:

```
\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[()]+
```

with the `perl = T` parameter.

---

A bit of an explanation:

```
\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # match any balanced parenthesis construct and let the engine skip it
|                        # or
[()]+                    # match single parentheses
```

Read [**more on backtracking control verbs**](https://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html) and see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/09YUHA/1/).

Answer (score 1):

`(\\([^)]*\\))*|\\)*` regex may solve the problem

Regex explanation may be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/ICgGkX/1)

- 2 alternatives matched.  First captured and second not captured.  Hence first wrapped in `()` and second isn't
- `\\(` matches literal `(`
- `[^)]` matches everything except literal `)`
- `*` matches previous token continuously.  Since `)` is not matched it reaches upto end of first pair of `)`
- `\\)` matches `)`
- `*` after group parenthesis matches these any number of times
- second alternative matches `)`
- all matches replaced by first captured group `\\1`
- hence, the result you want

```r
test <- structure(list(t1 = c("Book (Pg 1)", "(Website) Online)", "Journal: 2018)", 
                              "Book1 (pg 2) book 3 (pg4)  something)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                             -4L))
test
#>                                      t1
#> 1                           Book (Pg 1)
#> 2                     (Website) Online)
#> 3                        Journal: 2018)
#> 4 Book1 (pg 2) book 3 (pg4)  something)

gsub('(\\([^)]*\\))*|\\)*', '\\1', test$t1)

#> [1] "Book (Pg 1)"                         
#> [2] "(Website) Online"                    
#> [3] "Journal: 2018"                       
#> [4] "Book1 (pg 2) book 3 (pg4)  something"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Would you please explain a little your regex master Anil?