# A regex to remove the pattern "[0-9]g"

Tags: r, regex

I have the following sample dataset:

```
XYZ 185g
ABC 60G
Gha 20g
```

How do I remove the strings `"185g", "60G", "20g"` without accidentally removing the alphabets g and G in the main words?
I tried the below code but it replaces the alphabets in the main words as well.

```
a <- str_replace_all(a$words,"[0-9]"," ")
a <- str_replace_all(a$words,"[gG]"," ")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to combine them into something like

```r
a$words <- str_replace_all(a$words,"\\s*\\d+[gG]$", "")
```

The `\s*\d+[gG]$` regex matches

- `\s*` - zero or  more whitespaces
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `[gG]` - `g` or `G`
- `$` - end of string.

If you can have these strings inside a string, not just at the end, you may use

```r
a$words <- str_replace_all(a$words,"\\s*\\d+[gG]\\b", "")
```

where `$` is replaced with a `\b`, a word boundary.

To ignore case,

```r
a$words <- str_replace_all(a$words, regex("\\s*\\d+g\\b", ignore_case=TRUE), "")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
> gsub("\\s\\d+g$", "", c("XYZ 185g", "ABC 60G", "Gha 20g"), ignore.case = TRUE)
[1] "XYZ" "ABC" "Gha"
```

Comment: Nice to see you again my friend :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following solution:

```
vec <- c("XYZ 185g", "ABC 60G", "Gha 20g")

gsub("[A-Za-z]+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[ 0-9Gg]+", "", vec, perl = TRUE)

[1] "XYZ" "ABC" "Gha"
```

Comment: What is this `*SKIP`/`*FAIL` part?

Comment: You can find detailed explanation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex
and also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68239696/how-to-only-remove-single-parenthesis-and-keep-the-paired-ones

Comment: and also this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992984/verbs-that-act-after-backtracking-and-failure/20008790#20008790
the explanations are so detailed and good that I just leave it to the hands of true masters of regex including dear Wiktor Stribiziew .

Comment: The `[A-Za-z]+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[ 0-9Gg]+` works for the current input. It matches one or more ASCII letters (with `[A-Za-z]+`) first, and once consumed, the match is failed, the regex index remains after the last letter consumed, and the new match search starts right there. That is why `[ 0-9Gg]+` only starts matching with a space or digit, but then it can match any one or more digits, spaces, or `g`/`G`. [This](https://regex101.com/r/mUYAFS/1) is a demo of what the regex does.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much for your explanation. So I guess if I used a pattern like `\\s+\\d+[gG]\\b` just like you second solution for the alternative it may solve the problem.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Sure, if there is any problem :)